# How to set custom weights in layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am looking at how to set custom weights into the layers.

Below is the code I work with

```
batch_size = 64

input_dim = 12

units = 64
output_size = 1  # labels are from 0 to 9

# Build the RNN model
def build_model(allow_cudnn_kernel=True):


    lstm_layer = keras.layers.RNN(
            keras.layers.LSTMCell(units), input_shape=(None, input_dim)) 


    model = keras.models.Sequential(
        [
            lstm_layer,
            keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
            keras.layers.Dense(output_size),
        ]
    )
    return model
model = build_model()

model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
    optimizer="Adam",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)


model.fit(
    x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=15
)
```

Modle Summary

[image]

Can anyone help me how to  set_weights in above code? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want, to put pre-trained weights in the model ? Or to push weights on specific layers?

Comment: I am new to Keras if possible can u please share both the concepts.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#set_weights

Comment: Can u show me an example weight matrix that fit to my the above code? because am facing some shape issue in my custom weight matrix?

Comment: would you like to set all weights to zeros?

Comment: if possible, can u show me another example because I want to know the shape of the matrix?

Comment: model.set_weights([np.zeros(w.shape) for w in model.get_weights()])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214807/discussion-between-bsp-and-marco-cerliani).

Answer (score 8):

You can do it using `set_weights` method.

For example, if you want to set the weights of your `LSTM Layer`, it can be accessed using `model.layers[0]` and if your `Custom Weights` are, say in an array, named, `my_weights_matrix`, then you can set your `Custom Weights` to First Layer (LSTM) using the code shown below:

```
model.layers[0].set_weights([my_weights_matrix])
```

If you don't want your weights to be modified during Training, then you have to Freeze that Layer using the code, `model.layers[0].trainable = False`.

Please let me know if you face any other issue and I will be Happy to Help you.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: I am facing some shape issue .can you tell me what should be the shape of  weight matrix by looking at the above code.

Comment: Can u show me an example by setting zero weight matrix to the above my code?

Comment: @BSP, Can you please specify the Architecture of your Model using the command, `model.summary()` so that we can understand the shape of each layer. Also, please specify Weights of which Layer you want to Set. Thanks!

Comment: I added a summary of my model. I think this is enough.

Comment: sry ,can u please show me another example other than zero matrix